# How to develop react with MaterializeCSS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, npm, webpack, materialize

I have installed MaterializeCSS through *npm*. But I am not sure how to use MaterializeCSS. I'm using webpack.

Can anyone suggest a tutorial or something for the support?

Is it good to just use Bootstrap or just jump into MaterializeCSS?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's material-css you wish to use? Or is it materialize-css?

Regarding importing the files, you can simply add these in your HTML (for bootstrap)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

From what I know, one shouldn't have front-end files as `node_modules` dependencies, so you could consider using a CDN instead of installing Bootstrap/Materialize via NPM. It's faster, too.

Comment: thanks avi for the hint.  after these months i feel the question was really silly as the webpack doesnt link the css frameworks . My bad as i was a begginer. Sorry you guys and thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, 
https://material-ui.com/,

Material UI is developed by google, react component implementing material design concept.

Answer (score 0):

I work alot on react materializecss
[React-Materialize-Boilerplate](https://github.com/mfahadtahir/React-MaterializeCSS-Boiler-Plate)
an example [Project](https://github.com/mfahadtahir/Nando-s-Restraunt)
have a look at the repo, in index.html you put your links and download materializecss from npm to use the animations and activations

- To use style simply add classes
- To add animations use

```
import { M } from 'materializecss';
```

and to activate something

- In class component

```
  componentDidMount(){
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    M.Dropdown.init(elems, {
      // if u have anything additional info to add
    });
    // or if autoinit
    M.AutoInit();
  }
```

- In functional component

```
useEffect(() => {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    M.Dropdown.init(elems, {
      // if u have anything additional info to add
    });
})
```